# How to fix: error: invalid conversion from 'const MyClass*' to 'MyClass*'

Tags: c++, casting, shared-ptr

I am getting this compile error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'const MyClass*' to 'MyClass*'
```

Here is the code:

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<MyClass> myClassA;
const MyClass* myClassB;
myClassA = std::tr1::shared_ptr<MyClass>(myClassB); // error here
```

I think I understand the error, just don't know how to fix. I need myClassB to be a const so how to convert/copy classB to a shared_ptr?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need a shared pointer to a const object:

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<const MyClass> myClassA;
                     ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't go from a const MyClass to MyClass.

```
myClassA = std::tr1::shared_ptr< **const** MyClass>(myClassB);
```

Comment: In a language where `*` has meaning it is awkward to use it for emphasis. You could use Clang's way of indicating bits by underlining with `^~~~~` for example.

Comment: @Matthieu M I know that, I wanted that part to be bold but you can't bold something when it is in a code. So I didn't put it in code but my editor decided to put it in code.