# Cannot convert MyClass* to const MyClass

Tags: c++, visual-c++, syntax, constants

I'm trying to add constness to a variable in C++, by VC is refusing to compile with `Error C2664 : cannot convert MyClass * to const MyClass &`. I've tried everything, done searches, read similar questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803521/question-about-const-cast-in-c), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484737/how-to-fix-error-invalid-conversion-from-const-myclass-to-myclass)) and I still can't solve it.

My function is defined as :

```
void ClassFoo::FuncFoo(MyClass* instance){
     Merge(instance);     // <--- Error C2664 -- cannot convert MyClass* to const MyClass &
     Merge(&instance);     // <--- Error C2664 -- cannot convert MyClass** to const MyClass &
     Merge(*instance);     // <--- This compiles fine, but doesn't work properly at runtime
     Merge(const_cast<const GFxTextFormat&>(instance));     // <--- Error C2440
}

MyClass Merge (const MyClass &instance){
}
```

What should I do to properly add constness to the variable `instance` so that I can call `Merge` with it properly?

Comment: The one that compiles fine is correct. What's wrong at run time?

Comment: Read up about const_cast<>  http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const` isn't an issue here, it will be added automatically. The issue is pointer vs. reference.

As far as the code you show us is concerned, the following is correct:

```
 Merge(*instance);
```

If this doesn't work at runtime, the problem is in the code you're not showing us.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make the signature of your method

```
void ClassFoo::FuncFoo(MyClass* const instance)
```

That seems to be the only way. In the original, instance is a pointer to non-const MyClass.  You could use `const_cast`, but would that be correct?

Answer (score 1):

As NPE said, the method `Merge(*instance);` is correct, but here can be the problem known on c++ as **"slicing"**, you can google it and try to detect it by experemental way.

The main problem is as described below:

```
struct A
{ 
  A ( const int value ) : myValue1( value ) {};

private:
  double myValue1;
};

struct B : public A 
{ 
  B ( const int first, const int second ) : A( first ), myValue2( second ) {};

private:
  double myValue2;
};

main()
{
 B child( 1, 2 );  // The "child" object contains two values.
 A parent = child; // Here the "slicing" error, but the compiler will not say anything.
                   // So, the object "parent" now is the new object of type "A" and it memory only one value. 
                   // By the way, it can not be downcasted to object of type "B".
}
```